# NHibernate intermediate table mapping by code

Tags: nhibernate, nhibernate-mapping, nhibernate-mapping-by-code

I know that there are similar questions to this topic on stackoverflow, but none of them could solve my problem. I'm stuck with it, for at least two days now. So here is my question:

I have two tables with a `Many-To-Many` relationship, like this:

```
Department * - * Person
```

I don't want to use a `Many-To-Many` relationship, but two `Many-To-One` and define the link table as entity.

The link table should be called "Lam".

**My entities**

```
public class Department
{
    public virtual int Id { get; set; }
    public virtual IList<Lam> Lams { get; set; }
}

public class Person
{
    public virtual int Id { get; set; }
    public virtual IList<Lam> Lams { get; set; }
}

public class Lam
{
    public virtual Department Department { get; set; }
    public virtual Person Person { get; set; }
}
```

**My mappings**

```
public class DepartmentMapping : ClassMapping<Department>
{
    public DepartmentMapping()
    {
        Id(x => x.Id, map => map.Generator(Generators.Native));

        Bag(x => x.Lams, col =>
        {
            col.Key(k => k.Column("DepartmentId"));
            col.Inverse(true);
        }, r => r.OneToMany());
    }
}

public class PersonMapping : ClassMapping<Person>
{
    public PersonMapping()
    {
        Id(x => x.Id, map => map.Generator(Generators.Native));

        Bag(x => x.Lams, col =>
        {
            col.Key(k => k.Column("PersonId"));
            col.Inverse(true);
        }, r => r.OneToMany());
    }
}
```

Pairing mapping:

```
public class LamMapping : ClassMapping<Lam>
{
    public LamMapping()
    {
        ManyToOne(x => x.Department, map =>
        {
            map.Column("DepartmentId");
        });

        ManyToOne(x => x.Person, map =>
        {
            map.Column("PersonId");
        });
    }
}
```

If I try to run my application, I get the following error message:

> Incorrect syntax near 'Index'. If this is intended as a part of a
>   table hint, A WITH keyword and parenthesis are now required. See SQL
>   Server Books Online for proper syntax.

Could someone please just tell me, whats wrong with my code?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The mapping **as is** is correct *(at least the same was working for me)*. So, the question is from where is coming your exception?.

Let's have a SQL SELECT query over your simplified table/entity Person:

```
SELECT id FROM Person
```

That would work.

**But if** - in a not shown part of your mapping - exists Person's some property, let's say **`Index`** like this:

```
// entity
public class Person
{
    ...
    // C# property named Index
    public virtual int Index { get; set; }
    ...
// mapping
public class PersonMapping : ClassMapping<Person>
{
    public PersonMapping()
    {
        ...
        // that by default would be column Index
        Property(x => x.Index)
```

That would lead to SELECT like this

```
SELECT id, Index FROM Person
```

And in SQL Server worlds, that will cause error:

> Msg 1018, Level 15, State 1, Line 1
>   Incorrect syntax near 'Index'. If this is intended as a part of a table hint, A WITH keyword and parenthesis are now required.

So, because your mapping shown above is correct, I would suspect some part like this

If this is the case, we can use

```
...
Property(x => x.Index, x => { x.Column("[Index]"); });
```

Comment: Hi Radim. Thank you for your answer! I was already expecting you, because I saw your answers on nearly every Nhibernate related question :) I never use a property named "Index" but I will check again! If this will not solve my problem, I can poste my objects with all properties.

Comment: *Disclaimer - NHibernate seems to have its best time over.. and few remains to answer... but while there will be some issue, I do not want NHibernate users to be alone...*. The `Index` as a property could be one reason, similar is here http://stackoverflow.com/a/3305103/1679310 but I am almost sure, that won't be your issue

Comment: It was like you expected it. I had a different table called 'Timezone' with columns named (index, name, time). The problem was, that I created like 10 tables at a time plus mappings without testing, so I completely forgot about this index property.

Comment: Great to see that sir ;) Enjoy Mighty NHibernate ;) good luck

Comment: Guessing the issue and having it right. Magicians always +1 :)